# Is an article determained by the possessive 's?

Tags: articles, possessives, determiners, modifiers

Today I came across the following sentence:

> *AI's decision-making process is usually too difficult for most people to comprehend.*

It seemed weird to me because I thought that the word *process* required an article, since it is singular and countable. Then I noticed this 's with *AI* and assumed that there is no article because this *AI's* serves as a modifier that somehow takes the role of a determiner (and the word AI as such does not have to had an article).

So then, it should be *AI's process*, but *the AI process*, for instance in a sentence like *The AI process is now optimised*.

If I am correct, then it should work the other way round, too, for instance with proper nouns that aren't used with articles, so the sentences *The London programme is now over* and *London's programme is now over* should both be correct.

Am I right or I miss some point?

Comment: It's not weird at all, but perfectly fine and normal. "The" functions as a determiner just as genitive "Al's" does. Note that leaving aside predeterminers, it is not normally possible for a noun phrase to have two determiners.

Comment: It is function, not part of speech, that is important here. Thus, it's not an article that "process" requires, but a determiner. "The decision-making process" and "Al's decision-making process" both contain determiners, i.e. "the" and the genitive "Al's.

Answer (score 1):

In English, it's not possible to have both a possessive "'s" and an article, so the "'s" takes the place of the article.

More info:
Articles are in a syntactic category called *determiners*. Beyond articles, this group includes "some", "no", "this", "that", and the possessive "'s", among others. For the most part, a noun can only have one determiner. In the case of your example, the determiner of "process" is "'s".

Answer (score 0):

It is often useful to write out a "long form":

**The process of decision making of artificial intelligence**

*BECOMES*

AI's decision-making process

*The purpose of game playing of children*

**Children's game-playing purpose**

As for proper nouns:

The London program and London's program are both correct but the long form is not:
the program of London. And that's the difference between the phrases above and this phrase.